# A farmer with $800$ ft of fencing wants to enclose a rectangular area and then divide it into four pens

Tags: calculus

A farmer with $800$ ft of fencing wants to enclose a rectangular area and then divide it into four pens with fencing parallel to one side of the rectangle. What is the largest possible total area of the four pens. 
 I know $2L+5W=800$, and the area of the pen would be $\frac{L}{4W}$.
 I replaced W with the equation for L and got $A=\frac{L}{(640-(8/5)L)}$ From here I need to find the derivative, and I can't seem to get it right. I also don't know what to do after that. 
 PS. I am sorry about the formatting, I am learning how to do it correctly once finals week is over!

Comment: The total area is $LW$. If you do the replacement you suggested, you should get $\frac{1}{5}(800-2L)L$, which is $\frac{800L-2L^2}{5}$. This should not be hard to differentiate.

Comment: The area is $(L/4)W$, not $L/(4W)$.  Your expression for area should end up as a polynomial.

Comment: Near duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127796/finding-the-area-of-4-rectangles/1835430#1835430